# ASP.NET MVC4, mapping views to an enumerable with multiple concrete types

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

A problem I've come into a lot is the following:

Usually I will have an IEnumerable come in from our CMS that will have multiple types, like this:

```
var headerNavigation = new List<IHeaderNav>() {
          new TextElement(),
          new TextElement(),
          new ImageElement()
};
```

Ideally, I'd like to pass headerNavigation into a View and have MVC find the corresponding view based on the name of the model. While I could do something like this in my view:

```
foreach (IHeaderNav element in Model)
{
    if (sth is TextElement)
    {
         @{ Html.RenderPartial("TextElement", element);  }
    }

    // etc...
}
```

It would be better if i just passed `return View(Model)` and have the loop and matching of view and type name done by convention. Is this baked into MVC and I do not know about it? Or is there a contrib project that does this? What would be the general way of going about this? Rewriting the view engine?

Answer (score 7):

This can be achieved using `DisplayFor` templates, declaring the `@Model` type for each different concrete element type.

As an example `Shared/DisplayTemplates/TextElement.cshtml`:

```
@Model TextElement
<h3>Text</h3>
<p>model.Text</p>
```

And `Shared/DisplayTemplates/ImageElement.cshtml`:

```
@Model ImageElement
<h3>Image</h3>
<p>model.Text</p>
```

Then in your view you need to loop the collection as follows, using reflection to locate the template at runtime:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.Items)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => item, item.GetType().Name)
}
```

Assuming the Items property is a `List<IHeaderNav>()` with the following model sent back in the post:

```
        model.Items = new List<IHeaderNav>();
        model.Items.Add(new TextElement { Text = "Text test" });
        model.Items.Add(new ImageElement { Text = "Image test" });
```

It will render the following:

[image]